# How to use VisualStyleRenderer in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, user-interface

In a small project of mine I've came across the need of a collapsible group box.

Searching the Net, I've found one [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/XPCollapsGroupBox.aspx). In [one of the comments](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2591001/The-test-program-crashes-if-you-run-it-with-the-Wi.aspx) there's an improvement on the original code that uses the `VisualStyleRenderer` class in order to acquire the `TreeView` open and closed glyph.

Running the code it draws properly the Plus and Minus sing as Windows XP would draw it, however in Windows Vista and Windows 7 the glyph for open and closed nodes are small triangles.

What kind of interface, class or PInvoke, I need to use in order to acquire the right glyph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, TreeViews have the same appearance as in XP in Windows 7 and Vista. To get the little arrow glyphs you need to set the window theme for the control:

```
SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L"explorer", NULL)
```

This can also be used for ListViews.

I'm not sure how the collapsible group box renders the collapse/expand button so I'm not sure how to get it to draw them with the Explorer theme.